# Function wont work after submit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a form, wich is generated by a ajax call and shown in a modal window after a click at a button.

Inside this form i try to use some functions for e.g. the bootstrap switch for checkboxes.

If i click at first time, the modal open and all is fine and work well.

Now i submit the form by a click on a button by a ajax call.

Now the bootstrap switch wont work - i see the normal checkboxes. In my console is no error reported.

What caused this error and how can i fix it?

i include the script in the php file where is send the ajax call and the form will generated from.

```
<link href="'.$vz.'assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="'.$vz.'assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("[name=\'checkboxname[10]\']").bootstrapSwitch();
</script>
```

Comment: this script is not sending anything by ajax, this is a bootstrapSwitch

Comment: yes, off course, but the script wich contains the bootstrap script is the one, wich is generated by an ajax call - maybe i havn't explain it good enough.

Comment: please update your question with the code needed to reproduce the problem